# How to record video and audio in angular 7 project using HTML5 video tag?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to record a 2 minutes video in angular 7 project but I haven't found any code.
I have tried webRTC and it also does not work

Comment: you can refer this article for this https://medium.com/@moneychaudhary5/how-to-implement-audio-recording-using-record-rtc-in-angular-2-de1967328c38

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/moneychaudhary/RecordRTCDemo

Comment: Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/recordrtc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-record, I think it's good for your purpouse